# Switching from table view to a ui scroll view upon rotation

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, rotation, tableview, landscape

I have an application that has a table view, when the device goes to landscape i want it to switch to a uiscroll view that has heaps of images i can scroll between. Kinda like the ipod app how you have all your songs in a table view and when u rotate you get album art work that you can scroll through.

I tried some tutorials on changing views but they didn't seem to work.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

For those who are interested, what i did was to only support portrait orientation in the table view, then have a listener for when the device orientation has changed. When the orientation changes, i push a modal view on top of the table view.

The modal view only supports the landscape orientations. Once again listen for a device orientation change, and when that happens, just dismiss the modal view.

Hope this helps someone I had a big headache over it.